Why is my function returning undefined when using another function as a parameter?
The problem I am having is with the following code:
/**
 * @param {(sentence: string) => boolean} criterion - a function that
 *  takes a sentence and returns a boolean
 * @param {string[]} sentences - an array of space-separated strings of words
 * @returns {string[]} the subset of `sentences` for which `criterion` returns true
 */
const getRelevantSentences = (about, sentences) => {
    const arr = [];
      if(about(sentences) == true){
        arr.push(sentences);
        return arr;
      }
}

This above function is supposed to take another function and an array as arguments, and then pass out an array of strings that make the function return true. In this instance, I am trying to test whether or not the specific "sentence" string within the "sentences" array makes the about() function return true. In other words, I am returning any strings that are "similar" to that of another string.
Below is the code that makes up the about() function:
/**
 * @param {string[]} topics - an array of topic words
 * @param {string} sentence - a space-separated string of words
 * @returns {boolean} whether `sentence` contains any of the words in `topics`
 */
const isRelevant = (topics, sentence) => {
  for(i=0; i<topics.length;i++){
    if (sentence.includes(topics[i])) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};

/**
 * @param {string[]} topics - an array of topic words
 * @returns {(sentence: string) => boolean} a function that takes a sentence
 *  and returns whether it is relevant to `topics`
 */
const about = (topics) => {
    return function(sentence) {
      return isRelevant(topics,sentence);
    }
};

The data used as input is:
const sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
const sentences = "I have a pet dog", "I have a pet cat", "I don't have any pets"
How can I resolve this issue?

if(about(sentences) == true) - But about doesn't return true or false, it returns a function.  You didn't call that function.  For example: if(about(sentences)(someValue) == true)  Whatever value is supposed to be passed for sentence in that returned function would be what you pass as someValue.

Or... Is that even the right about?  In getRelevantSentences the about variable is local.  What are you passing to that function?  Please update the question to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example.

The if(about(sentences) isn't the same as const about.  How do you call getRelevantSentences?

Possibly off topic: const isRelevant returns true/false on the first iteration - remove the else and move the return false outside the loop.

Both abouts are the same. Is there a different way I need to be calling about ?

They're the same if you call getRelevantSentences like getRelevantSentences(about, arr) - but we can't see how you call it, so can't confirm and can't help your further.

Continued with new question applying the answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78438924/how-do-i-compare-an-array-of-strings-with-a-single-string-using-these-methods

As it stands, the function returns nothing (undefined) whenever about(sentences) is false. Please rewrite the function as follows:
const getRelevantSentences = (about, sentences) => {
    const arr = [];
    if(about(sentences)){
        arr.push(sentences);
    }
    return arr;
}

Or, as follows:
const getRelevantSentences = (about, sentences) => {
    if(about(sentences)){
        return [sentences];
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}


Thanks, this solved the undefined issue! Now the problem is with the function itself displaying the correct information :/

@antjuh dont forget to accept and upvote the answer (the gray checkbox and the arrow up), that's how stackoverflow works

Apologies, thank you!
